Add SSL certificate to python requests for all environments
As the title states. Company enabled SSL inspection which blocks every call made by request due to ssl failure. Yes I could go the easy route and just set verify=False but that isn't really a clean and sustainable solution especially for modular code.
Anyway from chrome I can easily get the root cert and I can add that to the cacert.pem of certifi package (I just copy&paste it in text editor). Yes it works. However I have multiple machines each with multiple separate conda environments.
So my question is:
How can I automate this for the existing environments?
For new environments?
After updating certifi package? (I assume that overwrites my changes)

The clean solution would probably be to provide the certificate to the request requests.get(url, cert=(cert_path, key_path))

which would mean doing it for every single request and thereby affecting the codebase with a network implementation detail?

Save the CA certificate to a file location that travels with your account.  On Windows, you can create a file in your home path:
C:\Users\<username>\certs\ca-root.pem

On linux, it can similarly be:
~/.certs/ca-root.pem

Then you can point conda to your CA certificate using the command:
#  windows:
conda config --set ssl_verify C:\Users\<username>\certs\ca-root.pem

#  linux:
conda config --set ssl_verify ~/.certs/ca-root.pem

This typically saves the setting to .condarc file in your user home directory, which also travels with your profile and conda should find with each use.
